# ReporteRs: How to write formatted table to both pptx and xlsx?

Tags: r, excel, reporters

I need a way to automatically create a powerpoint presentation with formatted tables of numbers, then also print these same tables to excel.

I currently have a formatted FlexTable object which I write to a powerpoint presentation with no issues using `ReporteRs`, but I am stuck on how to write the same table to Excel without having to go through all the formatting steps again.

Within R, Is there a way to either:

**A)** Write a flextable formatted object from R to excel?

or

**B)** Copy a formatted Excel table from xlsx file to powerpoint?

All thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to write a table to an Excel workbook, but with formatting (e.g., with gridlines, merged cells, colored text, etc.) or you just want to write the table's column names and values to excel? I think ReporteRs and FlexTable are intended for output to Word and Powerpoint or to html. You can use the `openxlsx` or `xlsx` packages to write data to Excel with formatting.

Comment: I want to be able to write a formatted table to both excel and powerpoint, using the same syntax/object from R. Since I already had the FlexTable constructed, I wanted to be able to use that format to print it directly to excel without having to rebuild the table in `openxlsx` Seems like it may not be possible

Comment: I am also trying to do this and the only work around I've found so far is exporting to Word and then copying and pasting into Excel. When I do so, all of the ```flextable``` formatting stays true.